# Cannot get SharePoint image

Tags: csom, microsoft

This is my first time developing with Microsoft and I'm having a lot of problems. I'm currently working on a project about PowerPoint plugins.

I want to get all the images in a folder in SharePoint, but I can't get them.

I keep reporting internal exception:

> IOException: Can't read data from the transfer connection: The remote host forcibly closes an existing connection.

[image]

```
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=基础连接已经关闭: 发送时发生错误。
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetIdcrlHeader(Uri url, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure, EventHandler`1 executingWebRequest)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, String username, SecureString password, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure, EventHandler`1 executingWebRequest)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, Boolean refresh, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.SetupRequestCredential(ClientRuntimeContext context, HttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.GetRequestStream()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetWebRequestExecutor()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at AI_PPT_BOX.Wpf.TemplateWpf.Apply_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in D:\Desktop\PowerPoint\AI PPT BOX\Wpf\TemplateWpf.xaml.cs:line 162

  此异常最初是在此调用堆栈中引发的: 
    [外部代码]

内部异常 1:
IOException: 无法从传输连接中读取数据: 远程主机强迫关闭了一个现有的连接。。

内部异常 2:
SocketException: 远程主机强迫关闭了一个现有的连接。
```

After the query document: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/authentication-errors-tls12-support

I added this line to the code：`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

But after the addition, the following error is reported again：

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException
  HResult=0x800488F2
  Message=The partner returned a bad sign-in name or password error. For more information, see Federation Error-handling Scenarios.
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetPartnerTicketFromAdfs(String adfsUrl, String username, String password)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetServiceToken(String username, String password, String serviceTarget, String servicePolicy)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, String username, SecureString password, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure, EventHandler`1 executingWebRequest)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, Boolean refresh, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.SetupRequestCredential(ClientRuntimeContext context, HttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.GetRequestStream()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetWebRequestExecutor()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at AI_PPT_BOX.Wpf.TemplateWpf.Apply_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in D:\Desktop\PowerPoint\AI PPT BOX\Wpf\TemplateWpf.xaml.cs:line 162
```

I don't understand why this happened. I want to get help.